# More efficient way to query this SQL table from python?

Tags: python, sql

I need to query rows where a column matches my list of ~60K IDs out of a table that contains millions of IDs. I think normally you would insert a temporary table into the database and merge on that but I can't edit this database. I am doing it like this using a loop w/ a python wrapper, but is there a better way? I mean it works, but still:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd


# connect to the database using windows authentication
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=my_fav_server;DATABASE=my_fav_db;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# read in all the ids
ids_list = [...60K ids in here..]

# query in 10K chunks to prevent memory error
def chunks(l,n):
    # split list into n lists of evenish size
    n = max(1,n)
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(l), n)]

chunked_ids_lists = chunks(ids_list, 10000)


# looping through to retrieve all cols
for chunk_num, chunked_ids_list in enumerate(chunked_ids_lists):
    temp_ids_string =  "('" + "','".join(chunked_ids_list) + "')"

    temp_sql = f"SELECT * FROM dbo.my_fav_table WHERE ID IN {temp_ids_string};"
    temp_data = pd.read_sql_query(temp_sql, conn)
    temp_path = f"temp_chunk_{chunk_num}.txt"
    temp_data.to_csv(temp_path, sep='\t', index=None)

# read the query chunks
all_data_list = []
for chunk_num in range(len(chunked_ids_lists)):
    temp_path = f"temp_chunk_{chunk_num}.txt"
    temp_data = pd.read_csv(temp_path, sep='\t')
    all_data_list.append(temp_data)

all_data = pd.concat(all_data_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameters rather than concatenating strings.

I don't see the need for the CSV files, if you're just going to read them all into Python in the next loop. Just put everything into `all_data_list` during the query loop.

```
all_data_list = []
for chunk in chunked_ids_lists:
    params = ','.join(['?'] * len(chunk))
    sql = f"SELECT * FROM dbo.my_fav_table WHERE ID IN ({params});"
    cursor.execute(sql, chunk)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    all_data_list.extend(rows)

all_data = pd.dataFrame(all_data_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way use [Psycopg's](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html) cursor.

```py
import psycopg2
# Connect to an existing database
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres")
# Open a cursor to perform database operations
cur = conn.cursor()
# get data from query 
# no need construct 'SQL-correct syntax' filter
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.my_fav_table WHERE ID IN %(filter)s;", {"filter": chunked_ids_lists})
# loop over getted rows 
for record in cur:
     # we got one record
     print(record)  # or make other data treatment
```